# Why isn't Spotify showing up in the volume-mixer?

Tags: windows-10, audio, audio-streaming, spotify, volume-mixer

Here's an interesting issue. The audio coming from Spotify desktop no longer appears in the system volume mixer (the program entirely, not just audio activity), and seems to be entirely bypassing [EqualizerAPO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/). This observed behavior seems to imply that Spotify's audio is not going through the "system effect infrastructure". Aside from the troubleshooting that I have tried below, does anyone have any suggestions as to why a particular program (in this case, Spotify) would not list itself in the volume mixer and how to remedy the issue?

Further details/Troubleshooting:

- Spotify is affected by the main volume control.
- Spotify appears to be the only program that isn't appearing as expected in the volume mixer.
- If **all** playback devices are disabled, Spotify still plays.
- I have reinstalled Spotify several times, alternating between installing from the store and installing through the SpotifySetup.exe
- I have reinstalled my audio driver several times (this actually started after I reinstalled my audio driver because my mic was marked as "currently unavailable" but all it took to fix that is to swap back and forth the default recording device.
- sfc /scannow doesn't find any issues, this is a fairly new installation to begin with of Windows 10.

[Link to image showing Spotify not appearing in volume mixer despite playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSLEX.png)

**Edit: I reinstalled Windows because that seems to fix everything. And it seems to have solved the issue described above. I will leave the question open in case someone knows what would cause a program to exhibit such behavior.**

Comment: If it helps, this does not happen on my system. Spotify there goes through EqualizerAPO and shows up in the mixer. So it is definitely something on your end.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. It was working for me too until, of course, it wasn't any longer (which was after yet another audio driver re installation). I suppose the issue at hand is figuring out what has gone wrong on my end to cause Spotify to act up.

Answer (score 1):

Found this after hours of frustration. 
In Windows 10
on the system tray right click on the speaker, then choose "open sound settings". Once in there set your output device to whatever is should be, in my case it was DFX Speakers (DFX Audio Enhancer) NOT Realtek but if you are only using the onboard, it should say Realtek or whatever your default onboard is.

On the Input is should say Microphone (Realtek High Definition).

Scroll down and you will see "app volume and device preferences", click that and make sure it is set to your default output device. For me it's DFX Audio Enhancer.

Once that is done, scroll down and look to the left for Spotify, to the right it should say your default output in the first of the two boxes, once you set that  you should see Spotify once again listed in your mixer settings on the system tray!

Answer (score 0):

This was going on for me, just now, and skipping the track ended up fixing it.  While trying to play/pause was not fixing it.